# Detect insufficient material in chess game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, chess

I have created a Library for chess game in JavaScript.

In this library i decided that game should only be over when detect checkmate or insufficient material.
Game is working properly for checkmate but I need to add function for detecting insufficient material condition to draw the game.

I have a object which is updated every time when one side piece kill piece of another side.

```
let count = {
   W: {
       K: 1,
       Q: 1,
       P: 8,
       R: 2,
       N: 2,
       B: 2,
   },
   B:{ /* Black piece */ }
}
```

So my question is how can i detect a insufficient material using above object in JavaScript.

Comment: What situation would you define as "insufficent material" ?

Comment: https://www.chess.com/article/view/how-chess-games-can-end-8-ways-explained#insufficient-material

Comment: Should be something like `!Q && !P && !R && (N+B < 2)`

Comment: I think it would actually be a bit more complicated than that article describes.  [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_chess#insufficient_material). You would have to keep track of the color of the bishop square as well.

Comment: You have the explanation for what insufficient material is, and you have an object describing how many pieces are left for each color. So what is the quesiton? You are basically asking us to write the if statement for you, if you managed to write an entire working chess engine then I am sure you can figure that out yourself.. :P